# splitter design

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

I want to split the signal from my electric guitar to 6 amplifiers. Does this splitter design look legit? I want to use 6 FET op amp followers to do it.

R2 - R7 are 47R to prevent oscillations (they're not 1k).

[image: splitter]

Comment: You should consider adding a DC blocking capacitor in series with the input. Also the 1M ohm resistor is quite high, you might get a lot of humm and noise when the input is not connected. I would use a 10 uF series capacitor and a 100 kohm instead of 1 Mohm. What will the supply voltages be? I also recommend to add some supply decoupling capacitors.

Comment: The supply will be +/- 15V. Yes i will use decoupling caps :) 100 nF for each chip + 220uF for each supply rail. I guess i must use 1M at the input, because guitar signal likes such high impedance output.

Comment: I also thought that DC blocking at the input is not necessary - guitar doesn't give you any DC, and the bias current of fet op-amps is low. But i will consider using it, thank you!

Comment: OK, it the input comes straight from the pick-up element or such and you know there's no DC then sure, keep as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the supply is a minimum of +/- 5 volts and you add decoupling capacitors to the Vcc/Vee lines on the op-amp packages you should be good to go. You could probably use one op-amp to drive two or three output lines and save at least 50% of the op-amps.

I'd also avoid using polarized capacitors in the output feeds - you cannot guarantee what the DC voltage levels might be between your circuit and what it feeds so use ceramic caps is my advice.

Comment: Nice thought with driving multiple output lines with one op amp - thank you!